# google map app location doesn't show anything

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed an android app that uses google map ,but when I run the app the map doesn't show anything!!!

I know its a problem with my API key but i can't get it right, here is how i get it:

1) from eclipse >> window >> preferences >> android >> build then i find my SHA1 fingerprint.

2) i go to the google API COnsole and make sure i chose the google maps for android v2 is selected.

3) create new android key and pasete my SHA1 fingerprint and my package name.

please help me :)

you can download my project from link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppx4iwvpqr3wvq3/android-my-map-location.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/create-and-obtain-api-key-for-google.html) which has a lot of pictures and graphics in order for you to explain the whole process. Its pretty short and clear.

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Maps Android v1 API in your code that has been officially deprecated and you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. Use this [Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) to achieve Google Maps Android v2.